# Can we use std::max in cpp for finding maximum element in a subbarray?

Tags: c++, std

For ex- if we have an array A ={1, 2 , 3, 4, 5}
and I want to find max element between A[i] and A[i+k].
Can I use max function for that , I tried to use it but I can't. Please tell me if they any other way to do it.

I need to do this

```
vector <int> max_of_subarrays(int *arr, int n, int k)
    {
        // your code here
        vector<int> v;
        for(int i=0; i<n+1-k; i++){
            int result = arr[i];
            v.push_back(max(result,arr+k)); 
        }
        return v;
```

Comment: "Can't" is not a good enough description of the problem. Please post a proper [mcve].

Comment: There is [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) for that. Also strange that you mix std::vector and a "C" style arrays (don't do that if you can)

Comment: Since you're using C++, and clearly `std::vector`, why not pass in two iterators instead of this bizarre C hybrid with an array pointer and some offsets?

Comment: (1) [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span), (2) [`std::span<...>::subspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/subspan), (3) [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [std:max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). It takes two iterators and returns an iterator to the maximum element in the specified range. You can use pointers to array elements so you can do something like:

```
vector <int> max_of_subarrays(int *arr, int n, int k) {
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<n+1-k; i++) {
        v.push_back(*max_element(arr + i , arr + k + i)); 
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Loving the in-line curly braces. So much easier to read, imho.

Comment: hey , its giving segmentation fault

Comment: This code fragment appears to be correct assuming that n is really the size of the array and k is positive number. Probably you have some other problem?

Comment: n is the size of the array and k is a positive number , actually, the error occurs when arr+i  becomes equal to arr+k and moves ahead. I fixed the error by doing (arr+i, arr+k+i).Thanks again for your time, it was really helpful

Comment: Sorry, you are right. This is a mistake on my side. I will correct it. On the other hand discovering it is even more educational :)